# Kaltura HTML5 Player changemedia

Tags: html, kaltura

I'm using Kaltura Player HTML v1.9.1 and we need to change media when the user click in an external player Button. The problem is that the media is not an entry of Kaltura, is an external URL. I try change media with videos hosted in kaltura, with entry_id, and works perfectly.

The code we have is:

```
function jsCallbackReady( playerId) {
    // Get the player Object
    kdp = document.getElementById(playerId);

    $('a').click(function () {
        kdp.sendNotification( 'changeMedia', { 'entryId' : 'http://example.org/4.mp4'});
    });
}

// Player.
kWidget.embed({
    'targetId': 'myVideoTarget',
    'wid': '_110',
    'uiconf_id' : '8705289',
    'entry_id' : 'http://example.org/3.mp4',
    'flashvars': {
        'autoPlay': true,
    },
    'uiVars' : {
        'streamerType'  : 'http',
        'sourceType'    : 'url',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it deleting and creating a new player with the new url. Is not the best solution but it works.

```
function redrawPlayer(playerId, url) {

    kWidget.destroy( playerId );
    kWidget.embed({
        'targetId': playerId,
        'wid': '_110',
        'uiconf_id' : '8705289',
        'entry_id' : url,
        'flashvars': {
            'autoPlay': true,
        },
        'uiVars' : {
            'streamerType'  : 'http',
            'sourceType'    : 'url',
        },
    });
}
```